# .Net Maui Xaml from new page base class is not displayed

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, maui

I want to create a new application specific page base class that is based on the contentpage class.  It is like a super page that has some content itself.  I would like all the content from app pages that use the new app specific page base class, to be added after the content of the new app specific base class.

I have the new base class created and I have some XAML in it.  The challenge is I never see the label controls defined in the app specific base class on my app pages.  I know I am missing something silly - probably dealing with the content property of the contentpage class but I have not been able to figure it out.  Any suggestions / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the XAML code for my app specific base class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:localapp="clr-namespace:GBarScene_Maui;assembly=GBarScene-Maui"
         x:Class="GBarScene_Maui.ContentPageTypes.GBSPage">

<ContentPage.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3"
                   Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3"
                   Offset=".16666" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F3"
                   Offset=".16667" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F3"
                   Offset="0.33332" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDF3"
                   Offset="0.33333" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDF3"
                   Offset="0.49999" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F8F3"
                   Offset="0.50000" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F8F3"
                   Offset="0.66666" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F2F5FF"
                   Offset="0.66667" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F2F5FF"
                   Offset="0.83332" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F7F3F8"
                   Offset="0.83333" />
        <GradientStop Color="#F7F3F8"
                   Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

</ContentPage.Background>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <Label Text="This is a test" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is the C# code:

namespace GBarScene_Maui.ContentPageTypes;

```
public abstract partial class GBSPage : ContentPage
{
    public GBSPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Here is the XAML for a new app page that is based on the new app specific content page base class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:GBSPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GBarScene_Maui.ContentPageTypes"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Shell.BackgroundColor="Transparent"               
             x:Class="GBarScene_Maui.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</local:GBSPage>
```

Here is the C# code for the new app page:

```
using GBarScene_Maui.ContentPageTypes;

namespace GBarScene_Maui
{
    public partial class MainPage : GBSPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `Content` property of the child page will overwrite the parent's content

Comment: @Jason - that is what I was guessing -- is there a way to merge the two so the content from the base class shows first followed by the app page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is markup that will autogenerate code at compile time, and as such is not inheritable.

For this, you can use `ContentPresenter` to achieve this.

A `ContentPresenter` can be placed in a control template to mark where content to be displayed by the templated custom control or templated page will appear. The custom control or page that consumes the control template will then define content to be displayed by the `ContentPresenter`.

You can refer to the following code:

**BasePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp821.BasePage"
             Title="BasePage">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                
                <Label Text="This is a test" />

                <!-- Content from child pages -->
                <ContentPresenter />
                
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mauiapp:BasePage 
             xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiApp821"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp821.TestPage"
            >
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Purple"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label  Text="this is the content of ChildPage"/>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</mauiapp:BasePage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage: BasePage 
{
      public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

      }
}
```

For more information, please check document [Substitute content into a ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter) .